# datalist how to tell if input is one of the options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering why why I select 2 with a select tag it returns true in the console. But Whenever I select 2 in the datalist it returns false in the console.

In short I need the datalist to return tru. I need to it be true so that when the user enters in the input I can ensure that the user has enter in a option I wanted (one of the drop down menu options )

```js
function castvote() {
    var selected = document.getElementById('vote');
    console.log("Chrome" in selected);
}
```

```html
  <input list="vote" onchange="castvote()" id="voteInput">
  <datalist id="vote" >
    <option value="Chrome">
  </datalist>

<label>Choose a browser from this list:
    <input id = "a" list="browsers" name="myBrowser" 
      style="width: 400px;" onclick="test()" /></label>
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
    <option value="Microsoft Edge">
  </datalist>
```

Comment: Could you specify what you mean with "datalist"? The HTML element? If so, I suggest changing it to `<datalist>` to make it clear for the reader.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to log? When would you want to log true/false?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.
I just put (`.children`) at the `getElementById()` to get all children of datalist and the `onChange()` function put at the input tag.

```
       <input list="vote" onchange="castvote()" id="voteInput">
        <datalist id="vote" >
            <option value="2">
            <option value="3">
            <option value="4">
            <option value="5">
            <option value="6">
        </datalist>

        <script>
        function castvote() {
            var datalist = document.getElementById('vote').children;
            console.log("2" in datalist);
        }
        </script>
```